# Parallelize Fortran vs Parallelize Matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran

I have the exact same code written in Fortran and Matlab. The code runs serially in both languages fine, but is substantially faster in Fortran. 
One of the loops of the code can be parallelized. In Matlab I achieve this very easily by just replacing a `for` with `parfor`.

Is there any such easy to it in Fortran? I am using Intel Fortran to compile the code.

Here is a very simple example of what I am doing:

Matlab code:

```
clear;
tic

gamma=5; 
beta=0.95;
T=5; 
r=0.015; 
maxw = 50;
minw = 1;
nw = 50;
nc = 50;
gw = linspace(minw,maxw,nw)';
gc = linspace(0.0,maxw,nc)';

c = zeros(nw,T);
v = zeros(nw,T);

c(:,T)=gw(:,1);
v(:,T) = (c(:,T).^(1-gamma))/(1-gamma);

for i=T-1:-1:1,
    i
    aux = v(:,i+1);
    parfor z=1:nw,
        auxV=zeros(nc,1);
        for j=1:nc,
            sav = gw(z,1)-gc(j,1);
            w_t1 = (1+r)*sav;
            w_t1 = max(min(w_t1,maxw),minw); 
            auxV(j,1)=(gc(j,1)^(1-gamma))/(1-gamma)+beta*interpn(gw,aux,w_t1);
        end 
        [v(z,i) imax]= max(auxV);
        c(z,i)=gc(imax,1);
    end 
end 
toc
```

With that `parfor` on the syntax computational time reduces significantly.

And equivalent fortran code is:

```
PROGRAM toy
IMPLICIT NONE


REAL :: gamma=5; 
REAL :: beta=0.95; 
INTEGER :: T=5; 
REAL :: r=0.015; 
REAL :: maxw = 50;
REAL :: minw = 1;
INTEGER :: nw = 50;
REAL, DIMENSION(1,50) :: gw, gc, aux3
REAL, DIMENSION(50,1) :: secd
INTEGER :: ind1, ind2, ind3

INTEGER :: nc = 50;
REAL, DIMENSION(50,5) :: c, v
REAL, DIMENSION(50,1) :: aux, auxV
REAL :: sav, w_t1
INTEGER, DIMENSION(1,1) :: pt
REAL :: aux1

c = 0;
v = 0;

DO ind1=1,nw
   gw(1,ind1)=1.0+(ind1-1.0)*1.0
END DO

DO ind1=1,nc
   gc(1,ind1)=0.0+(ind1-1.0)*1.0
END DO

aux3(1,:) = gw(1,:)

c(:,T)=gw(1,:);
v(:,T) = (c(:,T)**(1-gamma))/(1-gamma);


do ind1=T-1,1,-1

    secd(:,1) = 0.0
    call spline(aux3,v(:,ind1+1),nw,gamma,secd(:,1)) 

    aux(:,1) = v(:,ind1+1)
    do ind3=1,nw

        auxV=0; 

        do ind2=1,nc
            sav = gw(1,ind3)-gc(1,ind2);
            w_t1 = (1+r)*sav;

            w_t1 = max(min(w_t1,maxw),minw) 

            call splint(aux3,v(:,ind1+1),secd(:,1),nw,w_t1,1,1,aux1)
            auxV(ind2,1)=(gc(1,ind2)**(1-gamma))/(1-gamma)+beta*aux1
        end do

        v(ind3,ind1) = maxval(auxV)
        pt(1,1) = sum(maxloc(auxV))
        c(ind3,ind1)=gc(1,pt(1,1))
    end do
end do

end program
```

Is there any simple way to parallelize that second nested loop just like the matlab?

Comment: Why is it relevant that you have MATLAB code? Please try to limit your question to the relevant information.

Comment: You MUST post the code. If it is huge, post the relevant part. If you are concerned about one particular loop, post that one. Also, have you tried to read or search anything about parallel processing in Fortran? There are tons of resources about that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Fortram is a lower level programming paradigm than MATLAB, meaning that good Fortram code will most likely always be faster than MATLAB, but also it will most likely always be harder to write.

Comment: @VladimirF, just updated the question with some code.

Answer (score 1):

Most current Fortran compilers support OpenMP. This is similar to Matlab Parfor, but not quite as easy to use. Suggest you try OpenMP, it should give you a similar speed increase to the speed increase you find with parfor. OpenMP is well documented and very solid.

Answer (score 1):

```
ifort toy.f90 -parallel
```

Maybe not as good as the other options like coarrays or others but give it a try, super easy to implement!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I added that on the Visual Studio, Fortran command line, but I get the following two errors:


Warning 1  command line warning #10161: unrecognized source type 'ifort'; object file assumed ifort 


Warning 2  command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/parallel' ifort

Comment: @volcompt You do not want to add ifort there, it is already there, that is the compiler! The Windows version of the `parallel` is `/Qparallel`.

Comment: Thanks. Still get the error:
" ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/Qparallel.' "

Comment: Sorry, mine is Linux and that works for me.  Try this https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/4-1-ProgTools_-_Automatic_Parallelization_with_Intel_C2_AE_Compilers.pdf

Comment: I think I found it. Now I am getting this error: "warning #10182: disabling optimization; runtime debug checks enabled"

How can I disable runtime debug checks on Visual Studio?